# making an instance of a class in Dart

Tags: flutter, class, dart, object, oop

i'm a beginner in Dart programming and i'm a bit confused when it comes to making an instance of a class,
suppose we have a class named `Student`
what is the difference between these two:

```
Student student;
```

and

```
Student student = new Student();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Student student;` you are just declaring a field that you can later store a Student object in. You aren't creating an actual object here.

At `Student student = new Student();` you are creating an Student object which is stored in `student`. You now have an instance of the Student class that you can use methods on by calling for example `student.study()`.

In dart (as of Dart 2), unlike Java, you can also omit the "new" keyword.

Which means you can write like this instead: `Student student = Student();`

Example of using both your provided rows would look like this;

```
Student student; 
student = Student();
```

Which however can just be writted like this: `Student student = Student();`

Comment: thank you so much everything is clear now .